# JSON web encryption using cjsoe

Tags: c, encryption, jwe

Any help please on how to use the [cjose](https://github.com/cisco/cjose) library with a simple JSON. JSON example from the [ietf-jose](https://github.com/ietf-jose/cookbook/blob/master/jwe/5_2.key_encryption_using_rsa-oaep_with_aes-gcm.json)

Can someone give me some indications? thanks

Comment: At 2k rep, you should know this is off-topic...  Voting to close.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I will update my question to be more clear and show what i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one to one correspondence between given Json example and Json examples from cjose. But you may want to understanding how algorithms are applied studying
 functions from [test](https://github.com/cisco/cjose/blob/master/test/check_jwe.c), 
especially

`static void _self_encrypt_self_decrypt(const char *plain1)`

```
static void _self_encrypt_self_decrypt_with_key(const char *alg, const char *enc, const char *key, const char *plain1)
```

with

```
 _self_encrypt_self_decrypt_with_key(CJOSE_HDR_ALG_A128KW, CJOSE_HDR_ENC_A128CBC_HS256, JWK_OCT_16, plain1);
```

and main test functions

```
START_TEST(test_cjose_jwe_node_jose_encrypt_self_decrypt)
START_TEST(test_cjose_jwe_multiple_recipients)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot. The tests are the best documentation :)